# Solution of the recursive equation

Tags: matrices, recurrence-relations

Given matrices, $D, A, B$ --> I have the following recursive relation:

$$ D_k = A - B^T D^{-1}_{k-1} B , \quad \ k \in \mathbb{N}_+$$

with $D_1 = A_1$. I would like to find a closed form solution $D_k$ of this equation if it exists.

(Also, is there a computationally-efficient way to integrate this eqn?)

Comment: Who said a closed form is possible in the first place?

Comment: @IvanNeretin Hi -- definitely not sure if it exists (the only eqn I think may be similar is Lyapunov's, but it doesn't seem like that) If it may be possible to find an efficient computational algorithm to integrate this then that would be great.

Comment: I asked *WolframAlpha* about the special case of scalars rather than matrices. The result looks quite [impressive](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=g(1)%3DZ,+g(n%2B1)%3DA+-+B%5E2%2Fg(n)).

Comment: @AxelKemper Hi -- It doesn't seem to have done much other than manipulated the expression, no? Thanks

Comment: Scrolled down to the solution?

Comment: @AxelKemper It says "Standard computation time exceeded..." :(

Answer (score 0):

To illustrate my comment:

WolframAlpha suggested the following for the scalar recurrence.

[image]